# cmake: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cmake, ros

When i try to run `catkin build` i get this error

```
/home/noronn/miniconda3/bin/cmake: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0
```

and when i try to run `cmake` i get the same type of error

```
cmake: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0
```

I run on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS with ros noetic.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things which you can try:

1. You should try Updating/Reinstalling libp11-kit0
2. Check the library version along with that check if ROS Noetic is compatible with it.
3. Check LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
   Ensure that your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is set correctly. It should include the path to the ROS libraries. You can add it to your .bashrc or .zshrc file:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/noetic/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Replace /opt/ros/noetic/lib with the actual path to your ROS libraries.